# Does express-uglifyjs tolerate missing semicolons ? (strict_semicolons)

Tags: uglifyjs

I'm using express-uglify 0.3.1, (uses uglify-js 1.3.4)
and I'm getting  parse errors for every missing semicolon.

The doc : https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/
mentions a strict_semicolons option, that apparently defaults to false.

How can I explicitely set it to false ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's the answer : express-uglify is hardcoding the option, here's a patch to allow overriding the strict_semicolons option 
https://github.com/max-l/express-uglify/commit/da0107b401ced5cefce1c158afc57446251345d6